# Angular: How to get multiple checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I might miss some basic Angular concept because my ng-change event marks *both* checkboxes instead of just one.

These are my views (html file) (note the `<input>` tag):

```
<li>
    <label for="id_trade_type_0">Trade type:</label> 
    <ul id="id_trade_type">
        <li>
            <label for="id_trade_type_0">
                <input id="id_trade_type_0" name="trade_type" ng-change="filterMarkers()" ng-false-value="2" ng-model="formData.trade_type" ng-true-value="1" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Pardavimas
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="id_trade_type_1">
                <input id="id_trade_type_1" name="trade_type" ng-change="filterMarkers()" ng-false-value="2" ng-model="formData.trade_type" ng-true-value="1" type="checkbox" value="2" /> Nuoma
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

This is the function that is in my controller:

```
$scope.filterMarkers = function() {
  $scope.clearMarkers();
  $scope.loadMarkers('/get_markers/?' + $.param($scope.formData));
  console.log($scope.formData)
}
```

When I remove `ng-model="formData.trade_type"` from my view, I am able to click checkboxes separately (but then of course the code does not work as it should).

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, Here is a way to store different checkbox values in an array

```
$scope.selectedValues = [];

$scope.select = function (item) {
   var index = $scope.selectedValues.indexOf(item.value);
   if (item.isChecked) { // adding the value if checked and not exist in array
      if (index == -1) {
         $scope.selectedValues.push(item.value);
      }
   } else {
      if (index > -1) { // removing the value if uncheked and exist in array
         $scope.selectedValues.splice(index, 1);
      }
   }
}
```

In template:

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='item.isChecked' ng-value='item.value' 
ng-change='select(item)'/>
```

The values you want will be stored in `$scope.selectedValues`, you can construct a query string from that values

Note: make sure your `item is an object`, and should have `item.value` property assigned to get the value

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately both checkboxes are checked when I click on one of them, maybe the reason behind that is that `ng-model` on both checkboxes is still the same (`ng-model='item.isChecked'`) ?..

Comment: Yes, I thought you were looping if you have multiple values, so each item will be different object. You must loop on the values to get this working

Comment: 1. You must loop on the values to get this code working,  OR 2. use different ng-model and use your previous code

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I am not looping, the fields are generated by Django framework's `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` : `trade_type = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Trade.objects.all(), widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'ng-model': "formData.isChecked", "ng-change": "select(formData)", "ng-value" : "formData.property_type", }))`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have used same `ng-model="formData.trade_type"` for both the input.

use a different model to store a different value

like ex: `ng-model="formData.trade_type_1"` and `ng-model="formData.trade_type_2"`

**Edit:** As you have different values, If you want to use the same model you can use radio-buttons instead of select box, then only one will be selected

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand the problem now. The worst thing is that I must use same model and now must find a way how to send both checkboxes value as `formData`.

Comment: use a radio-button instead of checkbox, if you want to use the same model and select only one value

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Plese check my controller. When I am using radio buttons in my other fields (just 1 selection), my controller's `$scope.loadMarkers` constructs an url of, for example, `/get_markers/?property_parent=12` or `/get_markers/property_type=23`. But in this partucular case I want to use checkboxes and I want my controller to construct an url of `/get_markers/trade_type=1&trade_type=2&trade_type=123` (that's why I need those checkboxes for and thats why I need same model). Could you please tell me what information should I search for to achieve such goal?

Comment: ok, I understood, i got a similar problem, i will post another answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

For both of your inputs you are using the same `ng-model` attribute. 
You can see example here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D